# Create a differential output signal

Tags: signal, differential, differential-amplifier

I need to supply the galvo driver with a signal **"Voltage Range ±3.0V p-p or ±10.0V p-p (Differential Input)"** - that's what it says in the datasheet. I have a 0-5V single ended DAC and differential opAmp [AD8132](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD8132.pdf). So, I am planning to create the differential signal by the following schematic:

[image]

The output of the DAC will give me a signal ranging from 0 to 5V and I can scale it down using *R26*. The other pot (*R25*) will generate the proper voltage to offset DAC's signal to 0V DC. This way, a 0-5V wave on one input and +2.5 on the other input will give me ±2.5V between the outputs of the dual buffer *U4*. These signals then fed into differential opAmp *U5* with G=1.

**Question 1:** is this the proper way to generate a differential signal? I believe that I could place a 0.1uF cap between *R26* and *+in* of *U4* and it would automatically offset it to 0V, but since a part of my signal is DC, it would compromise the signal, right?

**Question 2:** What should I measure on each of the differential outputs of *U5* relative to ground?

Comment: Your circuit is not going to work without connecting U5 and U6 to a power source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Gain:**

I believe the gain in this design is too low to get a +/-10V output signal.

$$V_{out diff} = \frac{390Ω}{390Ω}.(V_{i+} -V_{i-})$$
$$V_{out diff} = 1.(5 - 2.5) = 2.5V_{diff-mode}$$
or 
$$+/-1.25V_{comm-mode}$$

Alternatively you could make use of the Vocm, instead of the V- input to offset the ADC value.

- **Question 1:**

Correct, this would destroy the DC component and is only possible if you could guarantee that the ADC generates a continuous AC signal, which I presume is impossible in your application. Even if that would be the case, you still have to take the lower cut-off frequency into account. Signals below 1Hz would require considerable capacitor values.

- **Question 2:**

You would measure an in-phase signal with half the amplitude of the differential mode signal on the +Vout pin and an opposite-phase signal on -Vout.

You may want to read this [application note](http://www.analog.com/library/analogdialogue/archives/43-05/adc_drivers.pdf) as well.

PS: You may want to consider a fixed voltage divider for R25/R26 in series with a smaller value potentiometer if calibration is needed.Like this for instance.

[image: Like this for instance]

This allows for more accurate calibration. The current single potentiometer design is very course.

Comment: Thanks for the app note - good one. The current schematic has problems because if I change DAC's output range using *R26* (say 0-3V), then I have to adjust *R25* to make 1.5V offset. Are you saying that I should connect DAC's output to the +in, 0V to the -in, and 0V to the Vocm and I do not need to generate the offset voltage on the right side of the schematic?

Comment: Correct. Wire the AD8132 as a single-ended input and use Vocm as offset, like fig 4. in the AN.

Comment: Not as simple. I want my signal to be offset to 0V, so I connect Vocm to ground. However, because my input signal is DC offset, I get this same offset on the output.